# Convert pdf not embeded font to png use Imagemagik

Tags: python, imagemagick

I use pdf file do not embeded font and convert it  to png. I try convert by command use Image Magic then i get error below and get some image.

```
 **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
```

Because i run command by `subprocess` of python do to get result image.(file name). This error make subprocess return error is:

```
SyntaxError: SyntaxError('unexpected EOF while parsing', ('<string>', 0, 0, ''))
```

And i can do something that. This problem only happend with pdf not embeded font.
So can i ignore this error or are these ways imagemagick ignore font not embeded ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem, but you could try `convert -quiet input.pdf output.png`

Comment: I think that error is coming from ghostscript, not ImageMagick.

Comment: @emcconville yes, i find this from ghostscript, so, how can i fix it.

Comment: You need to evaluate how the PDF is created, and identify what is corrupting the content-stream. The messages seem to suggest data loss.

Comment: Perhaps you have too old a version of Ghostscript. Try using GS 9.23, 9.24, or 9.25. I have heard of issues with 9.26 and 9.27.